# How to search data from current month 25 to next month 26

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about searching data by date period.

The time period of my search is the 26th of a month to the 25th of a month.
We according to the Getdate() to search data period.
example,

- getdate()=2023-06-20, we need search the data from 2023-05-26 to 2023-06-25
- getdate()=2023-06-25, we need search the data from 2023-05-26 to 2023-06-25
- getdate()=2023-06-26, we need search the data from 2023-06-26 to 2023-07-25
- getdate()=2023-07-01, we need search the data from 2023-06-26 to 2023-07-25

I had to try as follow to search current month data.
We will use triggers to do this.

```
Declare @CurrentDate datetime;  Set @CurrentDate='2023-06-29'
Select    START_DATE=dateadd(month,0,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate),MONTH(@CurrentDate),26))
Select END_DATE=dateadd(month,1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate), MONTH(@CurrentDate),25))`
```

Result: START_DATE=2023-06-26, END_DATE=2023-07-25

Or:

```
Declare @CurrentDate datetime;
Set @CurrentDate='2023-07-01'
Select START_DATE=dateadd(month,0,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate),MONTH(@CurrentDate),26)) 
Select END_DATE=dateadd(month,1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate), MONTH(@CurrentDate),25)) `
```

Result: START_DATE=2023-07-26, END_DATE=2023-08-25

We need to search the period of data from 2023-06-26 to 2023-07-25 when the getdate() in 2023-06-26 to 2023-07-25.You can see if the date became 2023-07-01, the current date period is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT getdate, 
CASE WHEN DAY(getdate) <= 25 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(day, 26 - DAY(getdate), getdate)) ELSE getdate END START_DATE,
CASE WHEN DAY(getdate) > 25 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(day, 25 - DAY(getdate), getdate)) ELSE DATEADD(day, 25 - DAY(getdate), getdate) END END_DATE
FROM a
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt, if I want to change to search last month, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by search last month?

Comment: If getdate is 2023-06-29, the start date is 2023-05-26, End date is 2023-06-26, thanks, matt